# What does the __attribute__((force)) do?

Tags: c, attributes, arm, clang

This sounds like something I should be able to Google, but I can't find a good reference.   What exactly does `__attribute__((force))` do?   As in:

```
 return (__attribute__((force)) uint32_t) *p
```

(this is for an ARM system, cross compiled with clang, but I can't find any reference anywhere on this attribute even in clang/arm specific pages..).

Comment: It's not even mentioned [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html)...

Comment: What is `p` by the way? `uint32_t*`?

Comment: Probably it is some local `#define` in a specific port? I would guess it's related to alignment.

Comment: have you tried to preprocess your code to see if `force` isn't a macro?

Comment: [Just tested it, not recognized, probably some non-standard or ARM thing](https://tio.run/#%23S9ZNzknMS///XzkzLzmnNCXVprgkJTOvRC/DjqsUSBsbxZcopGnAmVoFmtVcCkWpJaVFeQoa8fGJJSVFmUmlJanx8RoaaflFyamamgow1ZpA5dZctf//AwA).

Comment: Looks like it is used with something called [sparse](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-sparse/).

Comment: @FiddlingBits made a good point, but it would help if you posted the type of `p` along will all attributes and storage specifiers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`__attribute__((force))` is used to suppress warnings in sparse, the c semantics checker of the linux kernel.

The [wikipedia article of sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse#Annotations) lists the following attributes as defined by sparse:

- address_space(num)
- bitwise
- force
- context(expression,in_context,out_context)

If you need more information about these, you can take a look at [the man page of sparse](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sparse)

In the linux kernel some these attributes are redefined in  [linux/include/linux/compiler_types.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/compiler_types.h#L11). For example `__force` expands to `__attribute__((force))` or `__bitwise` to `__attribute__((bitwise))`.

However the [linux documentation about sparse](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/dev-tools/sparse.html) tells us, that gcc ignores these attributes:

> And with gcc, all the “__bitwise”/”__force stuff” goes away, and it all ends up looking just like integers to gcc.